# Passing java script value to another page

Tags: php

I have a page here prompt get an input and stores in a variable called ans,i need to pass this value to y.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function s()
{
var ans = prompt("Name your query?","");
}
</script>
<input type="image" src="images/savn.jpg" onclick="s();" />
<form method=post" action="y.php">
```

below here it has some text boxes so,i need this values also to be posted to y.php

I am struck.Can,any one take me further to next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place on your page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ans" name="ans" value="" />
```

Following the line `var ans = prompt("Name your query?","");`, add the line:

```
document.getElementById("ans").value = ans;
```

This should guarantee that you can access the variable "ans" on the page y.php as variable `$_POST['ans']`.

Comment: I am getting this [object HTMLInputElement] in y.php.I did not get prompt input.

Comment: I'm assuming the function s gets run first, so presumably you'd click on the image first and then submit?  You should see some sort of prompt.

Comment: @Neil:I need to save only after two text boxes.How do i do it?

Comment: Add a function testValid which checks if values have been inserted:  `if(document.getElementById('textbox1').value.length == 0) return false;` and add that method in the event onsubmit="return testValid()" in the form tag.  You can move the prompt for ans *after* you do the validation so it only asks when you've inserted valid values.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @neil:i have a textb enter data and text box2 enter data so here above prompt should get ip only if 2 text box values are present

Comment: Here i use that image as submit

Comment: According to what you've written, the image doesn't submit.  You either need an `<input type="submit" />` or you need to call submit on the form tag, neither of which you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden form element and set it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function s()
{
  document.getElementById('ans').value = prompt("Name your query?","");
}
</script>
<input type="image" src="images/savn.jpg" onclick="s();" />
<input type="hidden" name="ans" id="ans" />
<form method=post" action="y.php">
```

Now when you submit the form, the form variable will be submitted back.